# Formatting decimal numbers in C#

Tags: c#, formatting, number-formatting

How can I transform these numbers

Examples:

1. 77.0227
2. 0.0803
3. 1.1567

Into these numbers respectively:

1. 77,02
2. 8,03
3. 1,16

This all needs to be done with the same "formatting". 
These values come from a stored Procedure in SQL , and they are always different, but they need to be in the correct format. They are all Percent Values.

Comment: You have searched with the term "round"?

Comment: What is the original format of the data? Is it `Decimal`, `Single`, `Double`? Or is it `String`?

Comment: `0.0803` and `8,03` are far from being the same number

Comment: Only strings have formats. Numeric values in .Net are considered unformatted until you finally convert them to a string, which should do at the last possible moment.

Comment: @aloisdg I assume 0.0803 is a percent value, but yes, needs to be calrified by OP

Comment: @TimSchmelter I have it doesn't help me unfortunatly .

Comment: @MichalCiechan The original format of the data is numeric(38, 4) in SQL

Comment: @aloisdg i can guarantee you they are the same number, well they are not the "same" but the number 0.0803 that comes from SQL needs to be transformed into 8,03 to be displayed properly on the report I'm making.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn It deosn't need to be a usable numeric / int value , it's only for display purposes

Comment: round, convert to string then replace point with comma

Comment: Why should 0.0803 be converted to "8,03" rather than "0,08" - it seems in one particular instance you are multiplying by 100

Comment: @aloisdg yes it's a percent value!

Comment: @PaulF Thank you ,you just solved my problem! 
I was making this a problem way bigger than it was!

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(77.0227.ToString("F2").Replace(".", ","));`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [fixed-point ("F") format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#the-fixed-point-f-format-specifier) to round to two digits:

```
decimal number = 77.0227m;
string result = number.ToString("F2");
```

If this doesn't give you the desired format(no commas but dots for example), then you have to pass the desired culture. Presuming you want spanish:

```
var spanishCulture = new CultureInfo("es-ES");
string result = number.ToString("F2", spanishCulture);
```

Comment: How do I exactly give the input.ToString("F2") the number i want? 
sorry for the probably dumb question .
The value i need to pass is stored in r[column.ColumnName] in my program

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani: or ensure an appropriate CultureInfo is used that uses comma as decimal separator.

Comment: @GustavoJose: i guess `r` is the datareader, then its `r.GetDecimal(r.GetOrdinal(column.ColumnName))`

Comment: `input` is the number (as constant, field, property or parameter).

Answer (score 0):

If you need commas as decimal separator you should need to specify the culture; like this:

```
string result = string.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es-ES"), "{0:#,##0.00}", inputValue);
```

I'm supposing Spain's culture (Spanish language), so trying with that code.

See a running example in [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oMQ0Z9).